# I want to get the ID of a row which i just inserted. May i know how to do it

Tags: php, mysql

Here is a code where i'm inserting some values to table row. in the next line i want the id of that row. may i know how can i get that. Below is the code.

```
$data = array(
'i_course_id' => $post_data['course_id'],
'i_cousem_id' => $crs_semister,
'i_event' => $post_data['event'],
'i_event_year' => $year,
'i_stu_crs_random_id' => $studentData['random_id'],
'i_no_scan' => 1
);
$this->db->insert('i_stud_crs', $data);
```

Comment: It's hard to tell which database abstraction/tooling layer you are using here?

Comment: it's mysql and am using it in codigniter model.

Comment: Which version of code igniter?  Details details...

Comment: $this->db->insert_id(); just after insert query

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html

Comment: Wow!! Thanks a lot guys!! Thank you Poria & Progrock!!

Answer (score 2):

You should get last inserted id with `$this->db->insert_id()` just after the `$this->db->insert('i_stud_crs', $data);`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the last inserted id as:

```
    $this->db->insert('i_stud_crs', $data);
    $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

$insert_id holds the last inserted id.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
$data = array(
    'i_course_id' => $post_data['course_id'],
    'i_cousem_id' => $crs_semister,
    'i_event' => $post_data['event'],
    'i_event_year' => $year,
    'i_stu_crs_random_id' => $studentData['random_id'],
    'i_no_scan' => 1
    );
    $this->db->insert('i_stud_crs', $data);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
```